# Is $\int f(x) dx$ and $\int_{0}^{x} f(x) dx$ the same thing?

Tags: calculus

If I plug in a value into the result of an indefinite integral, which part of the area do I get?

Comment: why did you assume 0?

Comment: An indefinite integral is actually a _family_ of functions, while a definite integral is a (single) number.

Comment: Certainly not as the undefined integral has an arbitrary constant, hence no specific value.

Comment: If I plug a value into the result of an indefinite integral, what area of the curve do I get? Isn't this area exactly the same if I choose the bounds to be from 0 to that specific value?

Comment: The writing $$\int_0^x f(x)\ \text{d}x$$

is wrong. You cannot have the same variable of integration as an extreme of the integral. The correct form shall be

$$\int_0^x f(x')\ \text{d}x'$$

Comment: The (more precisely, *an*) indefinite integral need not coincide with the area of any part of the integrand. For example, if $f(x) = 0$ for all $x$, then the area taken over any interval is zero, but $F(x) = c$ is a perfectly valid indefinite integral for any constant $c$. When computing the area over some interval $[a,b]$, we have $\int_a^b f(x) dx = F(b) - F(a)$. Notice that any constant $c$ is cancelled in the subtraction, so we can use any antiderivative when computing the area.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Suppose that $F(x)$ is a primitive of $f(x)$, that is:

$$\frac{d}{dx}F(x) = f(x).$$

Then:
$$\int f(x) dx = F(x) + c, ~\forall c \in \mathbb{R},$$

while

$$\int_{0}^{x} f(x) dx = F(x) - F(0).$$

They are the same if you consider $c = -F(0).$

Answer (score 1):

In general you have

$$\frac{d}{dx}F(x)=f(x)$$
$$\implies$$
$$\int_a^xf(t)dt=\int f(x)dx=F(x)+c\iff F(a)=-c$$

Answer (score 0):

No it's not, in general:

$$\int f(x)\ \text{d}x = F(x) + c$$

Where $F(x)$ is the primitive of $f(x)$, provided it exist.

Whilst

$$\int_0^x f(x')\ \text{d}x' = F(x) - F(0)$$

And you cannot know if $F(0) = 0$ a priori.

Take $F(0) = -c$ and you're done, eventually.

Answer (score 0):

You need to be concern with the variables (not that it's a big deal if you know what you're doing but still....)
Then from the definition of the anti-derivative and Fundamental theorem of Calculus-part II, it follows respectively the answer given below.

Answer (score 0):

$\color{green}{\int_0^xf(x)\,\mathrm{d}x} = \color{orange}{F(x)-F(0)}$, which is a $\color{green}{\bf{definite\;integral}}$, or a $\color{orange}{\bf{value}}$.

$\color{green}{\int f(x)\,\mathrm{d}x} = \color{orange}{F(x)+c} = \color{blue}{\{F(x)\,|\,\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}F(x) = f(x)\}} = \color{purple}{[F(x)]}$ which is an $\color{green}{\bf{indefinite\;integral}}$ or an $\color{orange}{\bf{antiderivative}}$ or a $\color{blue}{\bf{set}}$, or a $\color{purple}{\bf{class}}$.